# Encode in CodeIgniter and then Decode in Python

Tags: codeigniter, encryption, python-2.7

I have stored the credentials like login, password by encoding them in CI like -

```
$login = "foo@example.com";
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$encrypted = $this->encrypt->encode($login);
//Then stored it in db
```

Now one of my python code wants to get the actual credentials. So by observing the decode of CI, I have written my own Decrypt module in python -

```
// Like CI get_key
def getKey(self, key):
            self.log.info("In getKey method with key : %s"%key)
            md5Key = hashlib.md5()
            md5Key.update(key)
            return md5Key.hexdigest()

// Like CI base64_decode
def getBase64Decode(self, encString):
            self.log.info("In getBase64Decode.")
            b64DecString = base64.b64decode(encString)
            return b64DecString

// Like CI _xor_decode
def xorDecode(self, string, key):
            self.log.info("In xorDecode method with string : %s and key : %s"%(string, key))
            mString = self.xorMerge(string, key)
            if mString == self.FAILED:
                    self.log.info("xorMerge Failed!")
                    return self.FAILED
            self.log.info("xor Merge returned %s"%mString)
            dec = ''
            for (x, y) in izip(mString[1:], cycle(mString)):
                   dec += ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)))

// Like CI _xor_merge
def xorMerge(self, string, key):
            self.log.info("In xorMerge method. with string : %s and key : %s"%(string, key))
            hashString = self.hashMethod(key)
            if hashString == self.FAILED:
                    self.log.info("hasMethod failed!")
                    return self.FAILED
            self.log.info("hash method retured : %s"%hashString)
            xored = ''
            for (x, y) in izip(string, cycle(hashString)):
                   xored += ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)))

// Like CI hash
def hashMethod(self, key):
            self.log.info("In hash method with key : %s"%key)
            hashStr = ''
            try:
                    hashStr = hashlib.sha1(key).hexdigest()
            except Exception, e:
                    self.log.info("Exception in sha1 %s"%str(e))
                    return self.FAILED
            return hashStr

// Like CI decode
def decode(self, string):
            self.log.info("In decode method. Decoding string : %s"%string)
            securitySection = "security"
            keyItem = "key"
            key = self.config.get(securitySection, keyItem)
            if not key:
                    self.log.info("Key Invalid")
                    return  self.FAILED
            key = self.getKey(key)
            self.log.info("Encrypted key : %s"%key)
            dec = self.getBase64Decode(string)
            self.log.info("b64decoded string : %s"%dec)
            xorDec = self.xorDecode(dec, key)
            if xorDec == self.FAILED:
                    self.log.info("Decoding failed!")
                    return self.FAILED
            self.log.info("Decoded string: %s"%xorDec)
            return xorDec
```

All of the above methods are written in Decrypt class of Decrypt module.

So when I pass the encrypted string to decode method, I get some weird unicode string and not the actual credentials. When I checked it with CI, `xorMerge` from above code doesn't result the same output as `_xor_merge` gives in CI. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a python module to "Decrypt what was encrypted in CodeIgniter using Encrypt library". `checkout` the code [here](https://github.com/hussaintamboli/Decrypt)

Answer (score 0):

if you use same `encoding/decoding standard` and and the `same encryption key` you should have no problems from language to language